# Changing text in EditText glitch

Tags: android, android-activity, textview

In my activity, I have a multi-line EditText so the user can store some notes:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/notesTV"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:hint="Enter notes here..."
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">>
</EditText>
```

In code, I create an outlet to this EditText. I then go to my database to fetch any notes the user may have taken previously and set these notes to the EditText's text.

```
package org1hnvc.httpshbssup.hbsnewventurecompetition;

import ...

public class Notes extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText notesTV;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTitle("Notes");

        notesTV = findViewById(R.id.notesTV);

        fetchNotes();
    }

    private void fetchNotes(){
        FirebaseManager.manager.fetchNotes(companyID, new FirebaseManager.NotesCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String notes) {
                notesTV.setText(notes);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "An error occurred while fetching your notes",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

When I do this, the application goes crazy. It exits out of the activity and goes to the previous activity (from which I segued). No error is thrown, but clearly the code is not properly executed. At first, I believed it may have something to do with my fetchNotes method. However, when I remove this method and just simply set the EditText's text to "test" in the onCreate method, the same thing happened. Somebody please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Activity is crashing because of this line:

```
notesTV = findViewById(R.id.notesTV);
```

You're asking the Activity to 'find' a View by Id, except you never told it which layout to inflate.

Make a change like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.the_layout_file_of_your_activity);

    setTitle("Notes");

    notesTV = findViewById(R.id.notesTV);

    fetchNotes();
}
```

In particular, the `setContentView()` part.

This way, the Activity will inflate the layout and make it possible for it to find your `notesTV` EditText.